# Bootstrap: панель навигации

Tags: bootstrap, вёрстка

Добрый день. Пытаюсь сделать панель навигации согласно примеру: http://bootstrap-ru.com/components.php#navbar.
Однако конечный результат получается не красивой горизонтальной панелью, а вертикальным списком с подсвечиванием элементов при наведении: [image]

Почему так происходит? Bootstrap точно подключен (bootstrap.min.css, jquery-1.11.2.js, bootstrap.min.js).
Код страницы [здесь](http://pastebin.com/6T5Wv4r3).

Comment: покажите ваш код. по картинке сложно что-то сказать

Comment: @boris_U: добавил ссылку на код в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Имя проекта</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">На главную</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <h1>Привет, мир!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @boris_U: спасибо! А почему не работает пример из статьи?

Comment: @DarkGenius, потому, что вы наверняка используете версию `3.3.2`, а документацию читаете по версии `2.3.2`.

Comment: @DarkGenius: может, с версиями bootstrapa что-то не так. Берите свежий bootstrap здесь - http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/


http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar - здесь пример navbar-а.